# C# / Unity3D - One constructor for all subclasses?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a noob, and a rusty one at that, so bear with me here. I want to make a digital implementation of an old, obscure card game. I have a Card type with properties such as name, rarity, classification, etc. Then there's more specific stuff that not all cards have, such as attack power, resource cost, etc. A fate card doesn't have a power stat, a planet card doesn't have an influence stat, and so forth.

I want to subclass Card out into these various kinds of cards with the appropriate properties that only they have, but I don't want to give up having a single "new Card(string name)" constructor. My idea was to have the Card constructor call a subclass's constructor with arguments for the general properties, but I read that you can't return anything from a constructor other than the type being constructed. Any way to do this cleanly?

Comment: A `public Card CardFactory(....` method that takes the same parameters as the constructor, and spits out new instances of the right kind of card?

Comment: Ah, you mean like an intermediate method that decides which constructor to use and returns the new instance? I don't recognize that syntax you're using, with the type and then method name.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's just a method that returns a `Card` and makes the decision about what kind of card to construct.

Comment: Dammit, I just realized that as I was opening up MonoDevelop... I haven't really done any programming in a year or something. Someday these things will stick.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, what you want to have in the end would be something like this:

```
Card planetCard = new Card("Planet");
Card fateCard = new Card("Fate");
```

Your plan of using inheritance won't work this way, as a base class cannot call a constructor of the inherited class from its own costructor. It can only happen the other way around. The two simpler options to solve this would be:

**1- Instantiate the propper class as you need it**.

Given two classes like this:

```
public class PlanetCard : Card
{
   ///--- Attributes of planet here
   public PlanetCard() : base("Planet"){}       
}
public class FateCard : Card
{
   ///--- Attributes of fate here
   public FateCard() : base("Fate"){}       
}
```

You can now create the cards as follows (which is kind of similar to what you wanted to achieve in the first place):

```
Card planetCard = new PlanetCard();
Card fateCard = new FateCard();
```

**2- Using Components instead of inheritance.**

The use of components instead of inheritance is very common nowadays when it comes to games. The idea is having only one Card class, but each card, depending on what it really is, would have different components to use:

```
interface IComponent{}
public class PlanetComponent : IComponent 
{
   ///--- Attributes of Planet
}
public class FateComponent : IComponent 
{
   ///--- Attributes of Fate
}
public class Card
{
   List<IComponent> components;
   public Card(string cardName)
   {
      ///--- Fill components according to the name
   }
   public T GetComponent<T>()
   {
      ///--- return the component of the type T in the list, or null
   }
}
```

And now you can create cards like in the first place (although the use later will be a bit different):

```
Card planetCard = new Card("Planet");
Card fateCard = new Card("Fate");
///--- Using the planet card
PlanetComponent planetComp=planetCard.GetComponent<PlanetComponent>();
if (planetComp!=null)
{
   ///--- you can use here the planet attributes
}
```

This solution is much more flexible, as it allows you to combine the components at will (you clud have a "FatePlanet" card with both components if you wanted). You will need though, some way of matching the name of the card with the components you want it to have.

Hope it helps!